# Use Facebook Live API for my mobile App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile, live-streaming, facebook-live-api

I want to use the new Facebook Live API to integrate it to my video-filter mobile app. So I can stream content generated from my phone. But I read in the documentation something about them not going to allow that.

Have anyone experienced anything related to this?

> Please note that Facebook's API should not be used to simultaneously stream content to other online services and that the API isn't intended for use with mobile phone cameras. Third-party ads should not be included in streams.

Does this mean, there is no posible way anyone will be able to integrate facebook live API in mobile. Only on desktops ?

Comment: They simply don’t want you to use it with mobile phone cameras, because of image quality. (Not only in terms of resolution, but also other stuff, such as shaky images, etc.)

Comment: Well.. but. what if I dont care, and I make an app that live streams to facebook live? Will it be taken down ?

Comment: what if, I want to my app to live stream on facebook which is not taken from the camera. I want my Running SIP call in my App to make live on Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

@omarojo: Any updates on this thread? What was the final answer or status of your app idea? Any updates would be great help if you can provide more details.

There is one app on app store named "Live Broadcaster" which does the same thing: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/live-broadcaster/id1145978146?mt=8

Facebook does not allow in their privacy policy for third party mobile app to use their live api: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#liveAPI

I wonder how  "Live Broadcaster" app is working with Facebook live and already live on App Store?

If any one has the workaround then please provide the details here so people can use the pathway accordingly to avoid FB policy issue and investing a lot money and efforts

Comment: I am also interested in the details of the Live API policy. Has anyone gotten any answers regarding the rules?